# SaltStack job detection

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, salt-stack

### Intro

Lately we've been noticing some weird behaviour in our production environment, apprently there's a task pulling the data from Prod Redis into Staging Redis, the process itself is managed by Salt.

### What I'm trying to achieve

Bottom line: I want to understand the triger for this action (There's no `schedule` command for this task, the command is being launched from the Salt master in a different manner).

### Some code

This is the `.sls` which is running this task:

```
redis-server:
  service.dead:
    - enable: True

fetchredis:
  cmd.run:
    - names:
       - /usr/bin/redis-cli -h {{grains['shost']}} --rdb /etc/redis-cluster/dump.rdb
       - gsutil cp /etc/redis-cluster/dump.rdb gs://redis-rtp-bkp/{{salt['cmd.run']('date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"')}}-{{grains['shost']}}.rdb
    - prereq:
      - service: redis-server

chown:
  cmd.run:
    - name: chown -R redis /etc/redis-cluster/*
    - cwd: /
    - user: root
    - require:
       - cmd: fetchredis

start_redis:
  service.running:
    - name: redis-server
    - require:
       - cmd: chown
```

### What I've tried so far?

I used all sorts of `salt-run` queries, either on specific jids that showed nothing or some errors.

Any suggestions on finding the trigger?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a good old cronjob? Which OS is your salt master running?

Comment: @dahrens Debian, I already went down that road, no user has `crontab`.

Comment: Does the job run periodically? Maybe it is just a user. How many people have access to the master? The event stream includes information about which user started a job. What errors appear on `salt-run state.event pretty=True`

Comment: @dahrens It's frozen for some reason, I'll try to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, next time I'll know where to look, there was an `.sls` in the Pillars directory, the content is as follows:

```
schedule:
 bkp:
    function: state.sls
    seconds: 600
    args:
      - redis.bkp
```

Thank you all for your kind help.